# Cannot create a symlink on Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: macos

I am trying to create a symlink in my project directory.

```
 ~/projects/myproject/path
 ln -nfs ../node_modules .
 ln: ./node_modules: Operation not permitted

 sudo ln -nfs ../node_modules .
 ln: ./node_modules: Operation not permitted
```

I this from System Integrity Protection? Is there a workaround without disabling the SIP?

Comment: Can you paste the result of `ls -ld ../node_modules .` ?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx+   18 username  staff   576B 12 Jun 05:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x  1086 username  staff    34K 12 Jun 05:50 ../node_modules/

Comment: Take a look at this : https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/